# Magento rounds £0.01p down at total

Tags: php, magento, math

I've been unable to find a solid solution to a rounding bug with [Magento](https://magento.com/) CE 1.9.

https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/97554/7857

```
public function roundPrice($price)
{
    return round($price, 4);
}
```

This held some ground but made no impact. So I'll try asking.

I have a product £25.00 inclusive of tax. If I add one to the cart grand total is £25.00. Tax is £4.17 (20%).

I then add a second (quantity 2). `£25.00 * 2 = £50.00` but this is not the case.

Total is £49.99, tax £8.33 (20%)

I've tried exploring [the famous floating point php issue](https://www.leaseweb.com/labs/2013/06/the-php-floating-point-precision-is-wrong-by-default/) but not soild came up.

Comment: Try printing the test prices with more decimal digits. Your case could result if the internal representation of the price is 24.997 which rounds to 25.00, but twice that is 49.994 which rounds to 49.99.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider php's [floor](http://php.net/manual/en/function.floor.php) function: `floor(25.01); // 25`

```
$price = 25.01;
$qty = 2;
$result = $qty * floor($price);
```

This will return 50 on the nose

Conversely, if you want to go up, use [ceil](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ceil.php).

Comment: This is a very limited solution. What if the single price is 25.30?

Comment: @LutzL we are talking about miniscule differences here. If its larger than that, there would be ways to deal with 30 cents as well.

Comment: That's why I wrote "limited", which could also read as "overly specialized".